# SQL - conditional statements in crosstab queries - say what

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working with MS Access 2007. I have 2 tables: **Types of Soda**, and **Likeability**.

Types of Soda are: Coke, Pepsi, Dr. Pepper, and Mello Yellow

Likeability is a lookup with these options: Liked, Disliked, No preference

I know how to count the number of Cokes or Mello Yellows in the table using DCount("[Types]", "[Types of Soda]", "[Types]" = 'Coke')

I also know how to count the number of Liked, Disliked, No preference.

("[Perception]", "[Likeability]", "[Perception]" = 'Liked')

But, what if I need to count the number of "Likes" by Type.

i.e. the table should look like this:

```
             Coke     |        Pepsi       |       Dr. Pepper     |   Mello Yellow   

Likes          9                   2                    12                  19

Dislikes       2                   45                   1                    0

No Preference  0                   12                   14                  15
```

I know in Access I can create a cross tab queries, but my tables are joined by an ID. So my [Likeability] table has an ID column, which is the same as the ID column in my [Types] table. That's the relationship, and that's what connects my tables.

My problem is that I don't know how to apply the condition for counting the likes, dislikes, etc, for ONLY the Types that I specify. It seems like I first have to check the [Likeability] table for "Likes", and cross reference the ID with the ID in the [Types] table.

I am very confused, and you may be too, now. But all I want to do is count the # of Likes and Dislikes for each type of soda.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not really clear (to me anyway) what your tables look like so lets assume the following

**tables**

```
Soda
------
Soda_ID (Long Integer (Increment))
Soda_Name (Text(50)


Perception
------
Perception_ID (Long Integer (Increment))
Perception_Name (Text(50)


Likeability
-----------
Likeability_ID (Long Integer (Increment))
Soda_ID (Long Integer)
Perception_ID (Long Integer)
User_ID (Long Integer)
```

**Data**

```
Soda_Id Soda_Name
------- ---------    
1       Coke
2       Pepsi
3       Dr. Pepper
4       Mello Yellow

Perception_ID Perception_Name
------------- ---------    
1             Likes
2             Dislikes
3             No Preference



Likeability_ID Soda_ID Perception_ID User_ID
-------------- ------- ------------- -------
1              1       1             1
2              2       1             1
3              3       1             1
4              4       1             1
5              1       2             2
6              2       2             2
7              3       2             2
8              4       2             2
9              1       3             3
10             2       3             3
11             3       3             3
12             4       3             3
13             1       1             5
14             2       2             6
15             2       2             7
16             3       3             8
17             3       3             9
18             3       3             10
```

**Transform query** You could write a query like this

```
TRANSFORM 
      Count(l.Likeability_ID) AS CountOfLikeability_ID
SELECT 
      p.Perception_Name
FROM 
      Soda s 
      INNER JOIN (Perception p 
            INNER JOIN Likeability l 
            ON p.Perception_ID = l.Perception_ID) 
      ON s.Soda_Id = l.Soda_ID
WHERE 
      p.Perception_Name<>"No Preference"
GROUP BY 
      p.Perception_Name
PIVOT 
      s.Soda_Name;
```

**query output**

```
Perception_Name Coke Dr_ Pepper Mello Yellow Pepsi
--------------- ---- ---------- ------------ -----
Dislikes        1    1          1            3
Likes           2    1          1            1
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually got similar results with a Crosstab query (not sure if it's the same), which now that I'm looking in the SQL view, is also using INNER JOIN ... ON. That's gotta be clue :) But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Jerry the transform/pivot is indeed the stuff that's added when you press the cross tab button